# Algorithmic error with colour changing - Android

Tags: java, android

I am struggling with some problem in my application. I am using canvas to draw text from textobject (which is stored in list) and when there is collision I want to change colour on red, from normal one which is saved inside textobject.

The most interesting thing for me, is when I am in both cases using Android defined color everything is working. I suppose that there is some algorithmic problem, but I can't find it.

```
public class Board extends ViewGroup{

Paint textPaint;

public Board(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
//...
textPaint = new Paint();
//...
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
//...
int i = 0;
    for (TextElement element : words) {
        textSize = element.getSize() * scaleMap.get(i);
        textPaint = element.getElementPaint();
            if (inContact == i) {
               textPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
            } else {
               textPaint.setColor(element.getElementPaint().getColor());
               //when there is for example textPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK); 
               // everything is working
            }
    textPaint.setTextSize(textSize);
    canvas.drawText(element.getText(), element.getX(), element.getY(),textPaint);
    i++;
    }
//...
}
}
```

Object of this class is created only once through whole application life cycle.

EDIT:

```
public class Board extends ViewGroup{

Paint textPaint;
List<TextElement> words = new ArrayList<TextElement>();

public Board(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
//...
textPaint = new Paint();
//...
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
//...
int i = 0;
    for (TextElement element : words) {
        textSize = element.getSize() * scaleMap.get(i);
        textPaint = element.getElementPaint();
            if (inContact == i) {
               textPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
            } else {
               textPaint.setColor(element.getElementPaint().getColor());
               //when there is for example textPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK); 
               // everything is working
            }
    textPaint.setTextSize(textSize);
    canvas.drawText(element.getText(), element.getX(), element.getY(),textPaint);
    i++;
    }
//...
}

public void addText(String newWord) {
    textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
    textPaint.setTextSize(35);
    textPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    TextElement newText = new TextElement(newWord, 35, textPaint, 10, 35);
    words.add(newText);
    scaleMap.add(words.size() - 1, 1.f);
    collisionMap.add(words.size() - 1, new RectF());
    }
}
```

Comment: all youre really doing is 'textPaint.setColor(textPaint.getColor())' since element.getElementPaint() is just a reference to textPaint

Comment: so you mean, that I should do in for loop something like: `textPaint = new Paint(element.getElementPaint())`?

Comment: you need to show more code. when and how is 'words' getting initialized? do you ever set the color of an element? are you getting an error?

Comment: @a_schimpf I've added code. I just call method addText and that is how something is implemented. Also there are no errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to repair it. I needed to make small changes in paint objects creation. There is working code:

```
public class Board extends ViewGroup{

Paint textPaint;
List<TextElement> words = new ArrayList<TextElement>();

public Board(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
//...
textPaint = new Paint();
//...
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
//...
int i = 0;
    for (TextElement element : words) {
        textSize = element.getSize() * scaleMap.get(i);
            if (inContact == i) {
               textPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
            } else {
               textPaint.setColor(element.getElementPaint().getColor());
            }
    textPaint.setTextSize(textSize);
    canvas.drawText(element.getText(), element.getX(), element.getY(),textPaint);
    i++;
    }
//...
}

public void addText(String newWord) {
    Paint newTextPaint = new Paint();
    newTextPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
    newTextPaint.setTextSize(35);
    newTextPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    TextElement newText = new TextElement(newWord, 35, newTextPaint, 10, 35);
    words.add(newText);
    scaleMap.add(words.size() - 1, 1.f);
    collisionMap.add(words.size() - 1, new RectF());
    }
}
```